# Convert output of LINQ to Int16

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got the following LINQ expression:

```
var ageEntry = from entry in args
                           where (entry.Key == "Age")
                           select entry.Value;

//I want age as Int16:
Int16 age = Convert.ToInt16(ageEntry);
```

However I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String],System.String]'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'.

which isn't the clearest exception I've seen, can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `ageEntry` is a sequence, being the result of a query. It looks like you expect your query to have a single result. Thus, you can say:

```
short age = Convert.ToInt16(ageEntry.Single());
```

> which isn't the clearest exception I've seen, can someone please explain this to me?

Actually, it's pretty clear. It's telling you that the type of `ageEntry` is `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.String,System.String],System.String]` and that it can't convert it. This is your major clue that `ageEntry` isn't representing a number or something that can be converted to a number like you think it should be.

Rather, it represents a query that filters and projects a certain sequence (in your case, `args`). Basically, `ageEntry` knows how to filter through a sequence of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` and project to `string`. This is why you have to use `Enumerable.Single`. You're saying "give me the one result from the query that results from doing all the filtering and projecting that you know how to do (by the way, throw an exception if there isn't a single result)."

Answer (score 1):

`ageEntry` is currently of type `IEnumerable<string>`. You may want to do something like:

```
var ageEntry = args.Single(x => x.Key == "Age");
var age = Int16.Parse(ageEntry.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ `Where` and `Select` statements always return collections.  Almost all LINQ operators return collections; sometimes the collection may have zero or one item, but it is a collection and you must operate on it as a collection.

The exceptions are

- `Single`
- `SingleOrDefault`
- `First`
- `FirstOrDefault`

Whenever you have a LINQ query and want to resolve it to a element rather than a collection you can use one of these operators, or an index operators like `list[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Your input is currently an `IEnumerable<string>` but you need a *single* `string` value as input - try this:

```
Int16 age = Convert.ToInt16(ageEntry.Single());
```

This makes the assumption there is actually exactly one string value in your `ageEntry` enumeration, otherwise it will throw an exception - Alternatives for `Single()` depending on your actual scenario are `First()` to take the first value regardless of how many are in the enumeration or `FirstOrDefault()` to take the first or a default value if there is no value.